# System not supported exception in IAsyncResult

Tags: windows, silverlight

i am trying to use `HttpWebRequest` for accessing a server. My application used to work on win7 and phone sdk 7.1 but now i upgraded to win8 and phone sdk 8, though my project is still for windows phone 7.1

Getting following exception in `IAsyncResult.ASyncWaitHandle`

```
base = {System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at System.Net.Browser.OHWRAsyncResult.get_AsyncWaitHandle()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Await/Async isn't compatible with WP7 or WP7.1

it's a new .Net 4.5 feature and not usable for these projects (which are basically Silverlight 3/4 projects).